# How to fix ‘TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'’ error in tts python code

Tags: python, tensorflow, text-to-speech

I want to train LJSpeech data with convolutional networks on my own. I've recently found auseful code on web. I set everything done, but just before the process of training (like a loading box shows up) i'm getting a type error. I have tried search for it on web, but nothing familiar came up. So i want to share the code with you to see if you can do something about it or show me what's missing.

This is where i'm working:

```
Desktop\dc_tts-master
```

This is the error i'm getting:

> File "C:\Users\mert_\Anaconda3\envs\merts\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 207, in **call**
>       ret = func(*args)
>
> File "C:\Users\mert_\Desktop\dc_tts-master\data_load.py", line 107, in _load_spectrograms
>       mel = "mels/{}".format(fname.replace("wav", "npy"))
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>
> ```
>     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
> ```

also this is probably the related part of the code with the problem:

```
def get_batch():
"""Loads training data and put them in queues"""
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # Load data
    fpaths, text_lengths, texts = load_data() # list
    maxlen, minlen = max(text_lengths), min(text_lengths)

    # Calc total batch count
    num_batch = len(fpaths) // hp.B

    # Create Queues
    fpath, text_length, text = tf.train.slice_input_producer([fpaths, text_lengths, texts], shuffle=True)

    # Parse
    text = tf.decode_raw(text, tf.int32)  # (None,)

    if hp.prepro:
        def _load_spectrograms(fpath):
            fname = os.path.basename(fpath)
            mel = "mels/{}".format(fname.replace("wav", "npy"))
            mag = "mags/{}".format(fname.replace("wav", "npy"))
            return fname, np.load(mel), np.load(mag)

        fname, mel, mag = tf.py_func(_load_spectrograms, [fpath], [tf.string, tf.float32, tf.float32])
    else:
        fname, mel, mag = tf.py_func(load_spectrograms, [fpath], [tf.string, tf.float32, tf.float32])  # (None, n_mels)

    # Add shape information
    fname.set_shape(())
    text.set_shape((None,))
    mel.set_shape((None, hp.n_mels))
    mag.set_shape((None, hp.n_fft//2+1))

    # Batching
    _, (texts, mels, mags, fnames) = tf.contrib.training.bucket_by_sequence_length(
                                        input_length=text_length,
                                        tensors=[text, mel, mag, fname],
                                        batch_size=hp.B,
                                        bucket_boundaries=[i for i in range(minlen + 1, maxlen - 1, 20)],
                                        num_threads=8,
                                        capacity=hp.B*4,
                                        dynamic_pad=True)

return texts, mels, mags, fnames, num_batch
```

So i'm not that much aware of the exact problem, if you don't know the solution but do have a confidence in that the problem occuring from somewhere else in code please let me know to make me share that part.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
mel = "mels/{}".format(fname.replace("wav", "npy"))
mag = "mags/{}".format(fname.replace("wav", "npy"))
```

with

```
mel = "mels/{}".format(fname.decode("utf-8").replace("wav", "npy"))
mag = "mags/{}".format(fname.decode("utf-8").replace("wav", "npy"))
```

in lines 107 and 108.

(https://github.com/Kyubyong/dc_tts/issues/11)

Comment: this has been fixed upstream